# Tapping screen causes current controller to return to previous controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, xcode10

Every time I tap somewhere along the top part of a view controller, it would return to the previous view. Root Controller is not affected as it doesn't have anything to return too. All of my View Controllers are affected though. (Please read update 3)

Things I've tried:

1. Looked for unnecessary gesture recognizer. (Result: I received nil when I check for the list gestures.)
2. I figured I might have accidentally added or left a IBOutlet to the view or something. (Result: There was no unnecessary IBOutlets.)
3. I disabled user interaction from a view to see if it would be affected. (Result: The bug seemed to go away until I enabled user interaction again.)
4. I've tried to do some research but I wasn't getting the results I wanted.

**Tapping above the green line will make the View Controller return to the previous Controller.**
[image]

I'm still relatively new to Objective-C and Xcode so I don't know if I'm making a rookie mistake or not.

**UPDATE (Please read update 3)**

Still nothing but here are a few more things i've tried:

1. Logging every user action.
2. Created a new project with new view controllers.
3. Opened a previous project to test it's view controllers.
4. Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode.

All attempts still came with that weird bug.

**UPDATE 2(Please read update 3)**

I've decided to put a band-aid over the problem. Since the bug doesn't work when clicking over a button, I put constraints on a empty button, put it on top of the background image and removed the effect when button is tapped.

I thought this would work but there is a few spots on the screen that activates the bug. I experimented and figured that certain parts of ui elements activated the bug. (Example: Some labels in a Stackview, top part of a textfield, a switch, top part of a UICollectionView, etc.)

I've disabled user interaction for certain ui elements. Unfortunately not all ui elements could be disabled because some require user interaction.

Also I figure out that tapping with three fingers on the screen somehow activates the bug.

Here is an error code I received in the console when I was trying multiple taps on the screen:

<_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer: 0x2822fc1e0>: Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

**UPDATE 3**

After playing around with the code again. I believe I've figured out what is causing the problem but not how to fix it.

I believe it has to do with the story board segue, or at least the transitions being used. If I set the kind to "Show(e.g. Push)" than it works fine, but if I set the kind to "Present Modally" and the transition to "Partial Curl", the bug does it's thing.

Sidenote: This is how I tested it. I created a new project (I don't think the language matters). The project has two view controllers; one button each with segue pointing at each view controllers. Segue 1 has it's kind as "Present Modally" and the transition as "Partial curl". Segue 2 is on the 2nd view controller and has it's kind as "Show(e.g. Push)". To test the bug, tap along the top part of the screen. If the bug worked, then it should show the partial curl transition but in reverse and send the user back to the 1st view controller.

Comment: This might be a long shot but is it possible to have a generic breakpoint on any type of user interaction? For example: break when the user taps on a UI Element or something of the sort.

Comment: It's a well known bug with partial curl. See duplicate for more info and workaround solution.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you are experiencing the standard swipe back gesture coming from the navigation controller. It thats the case try this code:

Objective-C:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Swift:

```
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: I typed the code in the viewDidLoad methods on two of my Controllers. It didn't seem to work.